# How to smooth data in matlab without using method from any toolkit

Tags: matlab, smoothing

I am trying to smooth some measurement data in Matlab and I think so, I am missing something. I wrote my own code to create the Gaussian window. However rest of code is copied from [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/272556) link:

```
% Generate sample data.
vector = 5*(1+cosd(1:3:180)) + 2 * rand(1, 60);
hist (vector)  ;
plot(vector, 'r-', 'linewidth', 3);
set(gcf, 'Position', get(0,'Screensize')); % Maximize figure.

% Construct blurring window.
windowWidth = int16(11);
halfWidth = windowWidth / 2 ;
gaussFilter = Gaussain (-5:5, 0, 1 ) ;
gaussFilter = gaussFilter / sum(gaussFilter); % Normalize.

% Do the blur.
smoothedVector = conv(vector(halfWidth:end-halfWidth), gaussFilter) ;

% plot it.
hold on;
plot(smoothedVector, 'b-', 'linewidth', 3);
```

Please help me correct my mistake. Below is the code for generating Gaussain Window:

```
function y = Gaussain ( window, mu, sigma) 
% y = exp (-((window - mu).^2)/(2*sigma^2)).* (1/(sigma * sqrt(2* pi)))  ;
y = exp (-((window - mu).^2)/(2*sigma^2)) ;
end
```

I am looking for a solution which does not use any Matlab toolkit's method. After fixing few things, I am getting this output:[image]

Comment: What problem do you see, exactly?

Comment: @LuisMendo: code is not behaving as it should. I am getting some out put and result data is not smoothed. You can try this code. Its working code.

Comment: I did. See my solution and tell me if it helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `WindowWidth` should be `int16(11)`, to match your filter. Or you could use `WindowWidth = int16(50)` with a filter that has 50 taps, instead of 11. With current values you are trimming too much of your output signal.

See figure with `WindowWidth = int16(11)`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOnW9.png

[image]

Comment: Try with 11, look at the figure, and tell me if that's the solution you expect

Comment: Or if you want to use 50, build a filter with 50 samples, not 11.

Comment: Could you help me build filter, because I do not want to use matlab builtin filter method. I have to translate this code in some other language.

Comment: Simply go to your code, replace 50 by 11, and tell me if the result is ok for you

Comment: Why did you change the last plot line?? It was ok as it was before.

Comment: I was not getting any output and due to which I edited last line in order to keep output in same figure.

Comment: Your original last line worked for me. Please see the figure I attached in my solution

Comment: yes, this time it worked for me. I think so there was some other mistake. Thanks for your help. I have a question if you can help, why first few points are not smoothed.

Comment: That's the transient introduced by the filter. In the first WindowWidth-1 samples the filter is not "full" of signal samples yet, and it gives output values that are biased towards zero. You just can't avoid that. What you could do is trim that part (in both signals) if you don't want to show it

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind help and precious time.

Comment: Welcome :-) I suggest you edit your question and leave it as it originally was: with `windowWidth = int16(11);` and last line `plot(smoothedVector(halfWidth:end-halfWidth), 'b-', 'linewidth', 3);` . That way the answer will make more sense to others who will read it

Comment: I thought, I corrected but may be I forgot to press save button. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was investigating in the same topic, founding this post that solved my problem, doing some adjustments and generalizations. 
With many thanks to the author of the previous reply, here is my generalized code, that works also with n-dimension points vectors

```
% SMOOTH Simple gaussian smooth function
% vector = input vector
% width = width of the smoothing
% window = width of the window to be used in the convolution
% 
% Credits: Generalization of a post made by User1551892 and Louis Mendo on 
% StackOverflow
% Created by: Leonardo Daga, 2016
function smoothedVector = smooth(vector, width, window)

% Check arguments and fill with defaults
if nargin < 2,
    width = 2;
end

if nargin < 3,
    window = width * 5 + 1;
end

% Rotate vector to a column vector (if needed) to make the code easier
if size(vector,1) > size(vector,2)
    isColumn = true;
else
    isColumn = false;
    vector = vector';
end

% Construct blurring window.
windowWidthInt = int16(window);
halfWidth = double(windowWidthInt / 2);
gaussFilter = Gaussian(-(halfWidth-1):(halfWidth-1), 0, width/2 ) ;
gaussFilter = gaussFilter / sum(gaussFilter);

% Do the blur, enlarging the vector to blur from the start with a
% convenient value and cutting the vector back when the blurring is done
enlargedVector = [ones(window, 1)*vector(1,:);
    vector;
    ones(window, 1)*vector(end,:)];

smoothedVector = zeros(size(enlargedVector,1)-1,size(enlargedVector,2));

for i=1:size(vector,2),
    smoothedVector(:,i) = conv(enlargedVector(halfWidth:end-halfWidth,i), gaussFilter) ;
end

smoothedVector = smoothedVector(window:end-window,:);

% Rotate back the vector, if it was a row vector
if (isColumn == false)
    smoothedVector = smoothedVector';
end

end

%% Create a gaussian vector to be used for the convolution
function y = Gaussian ( window, mu, sigma)
y = exp (-((window - mu).^2)/(2*sigma^2)) ;
end
```

You can run this function with the following sample code:

```
% Generate sample data.
vector = [5*(1+cosd(1:3:900)) + 2 * rand(1, 300);
    5*(1+sind(1:3:900)) + 2 * rand(1, 300)];

smoothedVector = smooth(vector, 5) ;

% plot it.
figure
plot(1:size(vector,2), vector, 'r-', 1:size(smoothedVector,2), smoothedVector, 'b-');
set(gcf, 'Position', get(0,'Screensize')); % Maximize figure.
```

getting the figure that follows:

[image: Smoothed cosine and sine with gaussian blur]